# How to get status report from Team foundation server 2015

Tags: tfs-2015

How to get a report from the  Visual Studio team foundation server with the following details.

1) User stories in Development bucket
2) User stories in Development- Review bucket
3) User stories in Development- pending deployment bucket.
4) User stories in testing bucket and their status 
5) User stories in UAT -complete bucket.
6) Bugs logged for the ACTIVE US.

Comment: Have you made an attempt to do so yourself? What have you tried? What didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

The information are all related to work items.

So, you can simply create queries and then create Excel reports from corresponding query.

Please see below articles for more information:

- [Create managed queries with the query editor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/track/using-queries?view=vsts&tabs=new-query-exp)
- [Create Excel reports from a work item query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/report/excel/create-status-and-trend-excel-reports?view=tfs-2018)

You can also reference below articles:

- [Reporting in Team Foundation Server – Part 7: Excel Reports from
  Work Item Queries](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sunder/2010/03/02/reporting-in-team-foundation-server-part-7-excel-reports-from-work-item-queries/)
- [TFS Reports using Excel](https://tech.lds.org/wiki/TFS_Reports_using_Excel)

If you mean SSRS, then you need to [Creat and Customize TFS Reports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ff647430(v=pandp.10)), just reference this article for details : [TFS Reports using SSRS](https://tech.lds.org/wiki/TFS_Reports_using_SSRS)

Comment: @Prathvi Channappa Ratnappagol Have you resolve the issue? is the answer helpful for you? any update?